# How to change the color of price of simple and configurable products in magento2?

Tags: category-products

I want to change the color of price of simple and configurable products on the category page.
Not on the product page.
Simple products price be blue and configurable products price be red.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to overwrite `Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml` into your custom theme.

Copy from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` into
`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Modify line

```html
<li class="item product product-item">
```

Into

```
<li class="item product product-item <?= $_product->getTypeId() ?>">
```

Then you can write a CSS rules like

```css
.catalog-category-view li.product.simple span.price {
    color: blue
}
.catalog-category-view li.product.configurable span.price {
    color: red
}
```

Thank you.

**References:**

- [Create a new storefront theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)
- [Templates basic concepts](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html)
- [Cascading style sheets (CSS)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html)

Comment: can you guide me to the directory of list.phtml

Comment: please tell me complete code hierarchy

Comment: if you override magento-catalog module earlier then go to   app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product and edit on list.phtml  .      If you not override yet then 1st override list.phtml on your theme directory then you will edit this code.(https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-override-template-phtml-files-in-magento-2/)  Follow this link for how to override.

Comment: can you please send me the full module? It will be of much help.

Comment: can you send me already overrided list.phtml code. Thanks..

Comment: you got it on  ( vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product  )  this path. then edit with above code and push on ( app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product )    this path

Comment: how to call css file in list.phtml

Comment: not in list.phtml write this css where your css file written earlier

Comment: i can't find it. will your please help me ?

Comment: please help me write css

Comment: i cannot find the file where the css is written and i can't override it. it will be a great help.